# Creating a backup protected with password

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I want to create a backup excel workbook encrypted with password whenever I hit a button save.

So far I have this but still can´t figure out how to protect all new .xlsm files with password so noone can´t do a change in backup files without knowing a password. Saving and creating backup files in different folder works.

Thanks.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)


    Dim DestinationFolder   As String
    Dim WbName              As String
    Dim WbExtension         As String
    Dim WbNewPath           As String
    Dim sHostName           As String

    sHostName = Environ$("computername")

    DestinationFolder = "C:\Users\An\Dropbox\Orders - backup"

    If DestinationFolder = "" Or Dir(DestinationFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder's path is incorect!", vbCritical, "Wrong folder's path"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    WbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

    WbExtension = Right$(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, "."))

    WbNewPath = DestinationFolder & "\" & WbName & sHostName & "(" & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy - hh.mm") & ")." & WbExtension

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs WbNewPath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.SaveAs` method. Then you can assign a password to the file.

Then just open your "old" version again.

Check out here: [MSDN - Workbook.SaveAs-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)

Comment: Can you please help me to modify my code with Saveas function? Im not sure how to do it with such a complex (for me) needs - date, time and computer name in filename. Thank you for efforts.